# Filtering models by eager loaded data, at the database level

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In the laravel docs they discuss eager loading related data to solve the N+1 query problem. I would like to filter my data based on the data from these relationships, without having to iterate through the results (that is, I would like this done at query time)

An example used in the docs is as follows:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

If I wanted to filter these books to only include those who's author lives in the zip code 12345, how would I do that?

Neither of the following queries work for me:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->where('zip', 12345)->get();
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->where('author.contacts.zip', 12345)->get();
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Eloquent?

Comment: You should be able to do something like this `App\Book::with('author.contacts' => function($q){ $q->where('zip', 12345)})->get();`

Comment: @Andrew That actually doesn't change the number of books that I get in the collection at all. If I use `toSql` to dump the query, I end up with `"select * from books"`, which suggests that's only filtering what relations are eagerly loaded, not filtering the books in the query, which I want.

Comment: Okay, my bad then. I've actually tried this query on my local machine, it should work just fine `App\Book::with('author.contacts')->whereHas('author.contacts'  => function($q){ $q->where('zip', 12345)})->get();`. I'll eat my hat if this doesn't work properly. Also look over [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321928/laravel-eloquent-orm-filtering-with-relationship) for reference.

Comment: @Andrew That works! If you write it up as an answer I'll upvote/accept it!

Comment: I guess it would hurt, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you're looking for you can use the following query:

```
App\Book::with('author.contacts')
->whereHas('author.contacts' => function($q){ 
     $q->where('zip', 12345)}
)
->get();
```

Arguably you could also use a similar query in the `contacts` model, something along the lines of this:

```
public function withZipCode()
{
    return Contacts::where('zip', 12345);
}
```

I honestly haven't tried it, but it should work.